# how to register domain with ampps for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, ampps

hi im trying to switch my localhost server from wampp to ampps but i am stuck in creating fake domain page, after i try to create my domain for wordpress, it says error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li0fW.png)

i tryed to go past this and install wordpress with this instructions https://antzbusinesssolutions.com/tips/install-wordpress-windows-computer-using-ampps/ but it still wont let me in to my localhost page wp admin

also when i try to klick on my domains it shows me error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUajV.png)

Comment: Have you entered your local domain into your hosts-file ( `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` ) pointing to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: yes i have done it

Comment: this is weird. when selecting a domain for the wordpress installation it doubles as such: `http://mysite.test/mysite.test/wp-login.php` but it's without css and when submitting user creds it goes to a 404 page.